# WebSocket closed with code: 1001 reason:Stream end encountered wasClean:0

Tags: ios, websocket, webrtc, kurento, apprtcdemo

I am trying to run AppRTC-iOS(native iOS video chat app based on WebRTC) I am able to connect web socket connection and also WebRTC able to receive sdpOffer.
When I am receive the call and video starts then web socket connection is getting close by saying this message **"WebSocket closed with code: 1001 reason:Stream end encountered wasClean:0"**.
Please share the solution or any idea if any body had this issue.

Comment: When your video starts, does Video library, controller comes from root window?

Comment: If App is opened and user received call from other end (For now from browser) and He accepts then user got push to next screen to start video conversation(WebRTC able to add the stream and generate sdp offers) but within nearly 5s web socket got disconnected.

Comment: I had the same scenario, but i used https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket library for websocket management, this doesnt disconnected while within call.